# Disabled Property not Changing

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#template').on('change', function() {
    var $option = $('option:selected', this); // get selected option
    var optgroup = $option.closest('optgroup').attr('data-customer-type-id');
    
    $('#winback').disabled = (optgroup != "2");
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <!-- other elements -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="template">Email Template</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="template" id="template" required="required">
      <optgroup label="Customer" data-customer-type-id="1">
        <option>opt1</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Former Customer" data-customer-type-id="2">
        <option>opt2</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Propsect" data-customer-type-id="3">
        <option>opt3</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="winback">Cancellation Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="winback" name="winback" disabled="disabled" required="required" />
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

I would expect that if I selected an option in the second `optgroup`, that it would enable the input with the id `winback` otherwise if I selected an option in any of the other `optgroups` that it would disable the input. But instead, nothing happens at all whenever I select a new `option`. It never gets enabled, it just stays disabled.

However, what is odd is if I check the value of my *optgroup* variable by using `console.log`, the value is what I would expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `disabled` is not exposed on the jquery object.  You should change

```
$('#winback').disabled = (optgroup != "2");
```

to

```
$('#winback').prop('disabled', (optgroup != "2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute value correctly using [`.prop( propertyName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

You can do

```
$('#winback').prop("disabled", optgroup != "2");
```

Check full code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#template').on('change', function() {
    var $option = $('option:selected', this); // get selected option
    var optgroup = $option.closest('optgroup').attr('data-customer-type-id');
       
    $('#winback').prop("disabled", optgroup != "2");
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <!-- other elements -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="template">Email Template</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="template" id="template" required="required">
      <optgroup label="Customer" data-customer-type-id="1">
        <option>opt1</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Former Customer" data-customer-type-id="2">
        <option>opt2</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Propsect" data-customer-type-id="3">
        <option>opt3</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="winback">Cancellation Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="winback" name="winback" disabled="disabled" required="required" />
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```